# Use CSS to change between displaying normal text fields & inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, html-input

Say I have a web page that displays information for a user account, with fields like user name, first name, last name, birth date, email address, etc.

I would like to provide 2 modes for this info:

1. Display mode: where the fields are just displayed as field name & value pairs that look like normal text (I don’t want the values to look like they’re displayed in disabled inputs)
2. Edit mode: where the field names are displayed like labels for field values that are displayed as appropriate editable inputs for the field value

I would like to switch between these modes by applying a CSS class (e.g., `edit`) to a `<div>` that displays the fields. This should then change from displaying the data as normal text to displaying it in a form with an appropriate `input` or other element for each field.

How can I do this using CSS as much as possible, and JavaScript as little as possible?

I can see 2 main approaches:

1. Always using the input & form elements in HTML, even when not in edit mode, but hiding buttons (like submit) & disabling modifying values  unless under a `<div class=“edit”>`, along with changing the look of the input elements to make them (when not in edit mode) just look like normal display text instead of disabled inputs.
2. Using non-input elements when just displaying data, then using CSS switch them to input elements when entering edit mode, and vice versa

I don’t know what effect the former would have on SEO, or other aspects around a web page.

I also don’t know which of these is easier to implement,or even if they are possible to implement without causing major problems (either for SEO, UI, etc.).

I know that JavaScript can edit the HTML DOM, but I’d prefer to do this only using CSS, to simplify the switching between the 2 modes.

Comment: What about using `"display: none"` on the form or the view-only depending on which mode you're in?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have entirely separate DOM trees for the view and edit modes and simply toggle the display of those seperate trees using `display`. Whether it's reasonable to have this much repetition depends a lot on your use case.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

function toggle() {
  container.classList.toggle("view");
  container.classList.toggle("edit");
};
```

```css
.view div {
  display: block;
}

.view form {
  display: none;
}

.edit div {
  display: none;
}

.edit form {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="view">
  <div>
    Name: Steve
  </div>
  <form>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input value="Steve" />
  </form>
  <button onclick="toggle()">Toggle view</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That’s possible. It just feels wasteful. But, then again, it could probably work fine, and the “wasted” resources are probably minimal compared to what’s available to a web page.